# URL RequestParameter JSP Error

Tags: java, jsp, http, url

Never thought I will be asking such a trifle query!
Please help with this stack:

```
    if(request.getParameter("cl")=="star"){
    txtFilePath = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/cl.json");
    }
else 
{     txtFilePath = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/kl.json");
}
```

Irrespective of passing **cl=star** in the url parameters, its not bringing any difference, and showing only **kl.json**
This code is in jsp, and as of now, no other framework is being used. It's being tested on Tom cat container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEVER** compare strings using `==`.

Always compare using the `equals` method.

```
request.getParameter("cl").equals("star")
```

Note that when using `==` to compare string objects, you are not comparing it's values but it's references.

Comment: Absolutely loved your answer, and am already embarrassed on the mistake ;)